# Installing WebStorm, not appearing in programs?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Linux. I want to install webstorm.

I have the files and run the `.sh` file in terminal which launches the software.

However it seems I always have to do this, I cant run it without having to launch it via terminal and I don't have any entry for it when I search my programs.

Is there no way to permanently install it like all other software?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [jetbrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/installing-and-launching.html#desktop_shortcut), it is exist 3 ways to create a desktop shortcut:

- In the Customize WebStorm wizard - when you run WebStorm for the first time.
- On the Welcome screen: Configure | Create Desktop Entry.
- In the main menu: Tools | Create Desktop Entry.

Then restart ubuntu and try to launch IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Hello infernouk and welcome to Askubuntu! From what I understand, you would like to run your software without opening a terminal each and every time. It is possible to do this through the use of what are called ".desktop files", which allow us to launch a program by clicking their icon (aka "launcher") in your application menu (aka the "Dash" in Ubuntu). According to [This official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles), you can easily create a launcher using a program called `gnome-panel`. Please follow the steps below:

1. Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`. You will be asked for your password; this is normal. Type your password and press ENTER, and note that there will be no asterisks shown as you type it.
2. In the same terminal, type `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications/ --create-new`. After entering this command, a window will pop up allowing you to enter the Name of the program -- in this case, WebStorm; and the Command used to launch the program, which you must specify the full path to (example: `./home/infernouk/WebStorm/WebStorm.sh`). You will also be able to add an optional Comment to describe the program, and you can add an icon by clicking the big icon on the left side of the window and then choosing an appropriate image file. When you are done, click OK.
3. Try searching in the menu for launcher you just created; it should be there. If not, then try logging out and back in.

Let me know if you need further assistance :)

Comment: Hi there! I tried this and understand the process, however it didnt seem to create the file and I cant find anything by searching webstorm even after relogging? I will give it a second go now. Im getting "Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
"

Comment: Hmm, so to confirm what you just said, there was no file was placed in `~/.local/share/applications/`? To check, you will have to open the Files application in the sidebar, right-click in the white space amongst the folders in the Files window, and then click "Show Hidden Files" in the right-click menu. From here, you must double-click `.local`, `share`, and then `applications`

Comment: Ah yes it was in that directory and is usable, for some reason the final command didnt launch it or anything so i didnt know it existed! many thanks, just having issues with not being able to right click 'open with' and select webstorm with html files and such now!

Comment: You're welcome! So to be clear, you found the icon, but clicking the icon doesn't launch the program?